# cucumber Gherkin issue - doesn't find the matching glue code

Tags: eclipse, cucumber, gherkin

I am learning BDD in cucumber-eclipse. I have downloaded all the jar's but still eclipse is saying it couldn't find definition for rest of the text.

```
Feature: Login

Scenario: Successful Login with valid Credentials
  Given user is on Homepage
  When user enters Username and Password
  Then He can visit the practice page
```

In above code, it couldn't find glue codes for below text:

1. user is on Homepage
2. user enters Username and Password
3. He can visit the practice page

Comment: Please share your file layout and the runner class. The problem you are facing can have many diferent reasons and we don't have enough information to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest possible start is to download or clone a getting started project by the Cucumber team https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton

Run it using Maven or Gradle. When you have it running, and it runs out of the box, then add Eclipse to the mix.

Answer (score 0):

Check these Options

Option 1:
Make sure you ran the code as Cucumber feature and get the skeleton generated with help of cucumber plugin

[image: Cucumber Plugin]

In your case, Cucumber will print like this

```
//Print start
@Given("^user is on Homepage$")
public void user_is_on_Homepage() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@When("^user enters Username and Password$")
public void user_enters_Username_and_Password() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@Then("^He can visit the practice page$")
public void he_can_visit_the_practice_page() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}
//Print End
```

Create package features.stepDefinitions and then create class file "ABC.java" with above generated skeleton. Proceed to Option 2

Option 2

If below class is the Runner, we need to have the glue of the feature file folder. Usually it will be in resources folder

```
package test.runner
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;

@CucumberOptions(
            features="src/test/resources/features/featureFileFolder",
            glue = { "features.stepDefinitions"},
            tags={"@UI"},
            monochrome=true)
    public class Runner{

    }
```

Finally execute the runner file as Junit Test

Note:

Tag UI is something we will use to link scenario and annotations.

In this case feature file will be written as.

@UI

Scenario: Successful Login with valid Credentials

Given user is on Homepage

When user enters Username and Password

Then He can visit the practice page

Hope this may help!